# Spring boot external config override isnt working

Tags: spring-boot

I have an `application.yml` and `application-qa.yml` in my resources folder.
I have an external `application-qa.yml`.
I want the properties in the external `application-qa.yml` to override the matching ones from the default `application.yml` and from the internal  `application-qa.yml`, I dont want to override the entire file.

Im adding this VM option (In Intellij): `-Dspring.config.additional-location=file:{absolute/path/to/external/ending/with/application-qa.yml}`

I also have in env variables (also in Intellij): `spring.profiles.active=qa`

And for some reason the override doesnt work, I get the value from the internal `application-qa.yml` instead of the external one.

Tried naming the external file as `application.yml`, didnt work.

**UPDATE:**

It does work if I remove `application-qa.yml` from the end of the path and just give a path to the folder where the file is, but I want to specify a file, I dont want him to take everything thats in the dir.

Answer (score 0):

This is a change in behavior from 1.x to 2.x. The spring.config.location overrides the default instead of adding to it. We need to use spring.config.additional-location to keep the defaults. So if you want to override try spring.config.location instead.

Comment: I want to override specific properties, not the entire file, sorry if it wasnt clear, will edit

Comment: You can still keep all the properties and override the selected fields in the external file.

Comment: How? When I use spring.config.location, properties that I have in the internal `application-qa.yml` disappear....

Comment: -Dspring.config.location=file:{absolute/path/to/external/ending/with/application-qa.yml}
external file should contain all the attributes of application-qa.yml in resource folder.